# how to do Partition in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

How do i partion my hardisk in Ubuntu and im having having a single partion, only one drive, the main problem is i could not parrtition my home drive by staying in home drive itself and i could not enter into BIOS (i have tried all possible ways) please help?Edit

Comment: Try to search the site before you ask a question!

Comment: I have read that already. And Im using the gparted app but the problem is im in my home drive and i cannot resize my home drive itself(not possible). And the main problem is i could not even enter the BIOS also. WHAT SHOULD I DO NOW???

Comment: You will need to boot from some other partition that you are not using - it cannot be mounted.  The liveCD/USB that is used to install is one good possibility.

Comment: i have mentioned that i have only one partition, My home drive thats all

Comment: Read the question I linked, because it clearly states that you need to **boot a live-cd/USB and make sure that the partition is unmounted**. If not then you can't modify it! **READ**.

Answer (score 0):

first backup your files (if you don't want to loose them).
burn any linux iso to dvd.
Boot the dvd  and go to admin tab and select gparted.

you should be able to partition any way you want.  If you loose the system just reinstall, and reinstall your backups